# iOS app closes unexpectedly

Tags: ios, iphone, out-of-memory

I have a problem with my iOS app I cannot solve. It keeps quitting and sometimes the whole iPhone restarts when there are other apps open (even background ones).

When looking with the profiling tools provided with xCode it seems that “ImageIO_JPEG_Data” uses all the ram available.

I attach you the images from the profiler. If you need anything else please let me know!!

[image: Allocation Profiling statistics]
[image: Allocation Profiling Call Tree]
[image: Allocations]

EDIT: found it! That’s the code causing it

```
-(void)downloadFromURL:(NSString *)url withPlaceholder:(UIImage *)placehold
{
    if (placehold) {
        [self setImage:placehold];
    }
    if (url) {


        if ([url rangeOfString:@"/Library/"].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:url];
            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            if (image) {
                [self setImage:image];
                [self setNeedsLayout];
            }
            return;
        }

        NSString *strImgName = [[[[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject] retain];
        AppDelegate *app=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        [app applicationCacheDirectoryString];

        // NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[AppDelegate sharedObject]applicationCacheDirectoryString],strImgName];


        NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[app applicationCacheDirectoryString],strImgName];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSString *aURL=[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]==NO)
        {
            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aURL]];
                [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

                UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                if (image) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self setImage:image];
                        [self setNeedsLayout];

                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            if (image) {
                [self setImage:image];
                [self setNeedsLayout];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code, breakpoints, things you've tried, anything to help diagnose the issue would be helpful.

Comment: The most important part of the question is missing. What's the app actually doing? Show code, provide details.

Comment: posting the code would be a problem since we are talking about a really big application and nobody is gonna read that :P I could write the appDelegate since it seems like it blocks right after starting.

Comment: ok, just paste the piece that is making the phone crash. Anyway, 200MB of image? thats crazy...

Comment: that’s the problem... I am not using any 200 MB image...

Comment: anyone? I honestly don’t know where the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it wasn’t a bug in my code causing it, somehow the sqlite database I was using got corrupted and removing the app and reinstalling it seems to have fixed it.